# Magento2.3 adding the products automatically to the parent category and to the subcategories which are on higher level

Tags: product, magento2.3, category-products

I am using Magneto2.3.0 I need this adding the products automatically to the parent category and to the subcategories which are on higher level

If anyone idea reply me how to achieve this requirement.
I am trying to below answer code than getting this

please check it my admin image

how to remove selected category above c d p b s options

[image]

here below  my catalog-category -section image there other brand category inside child category assign it automatically like c d p b s. if i assign shop by department->beauty & personal care->hair->seriums/oils but in above this category other parent category inside child category assign it. so this is wrong to our requirement wise.i share you my category structure below image mentioned

[image]

please check i have to install other default magento setup inside this code apply after getting this using luma theme by default.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are talking about in admin category assignment?

Comment: yes i am talking in admin side product edit page

Comment: if you have any idea reply me

Comment: you can override `web/js/form/element/ui-select.js` js and modify that according to your need.

Comment: you will get all categories in `this` objects by which you can select/unselect categories.

Comment: actually i need in backend side when user create product after category choose there if i select child cateogry automatically assign parent category after save but there showing checkbox click

Comment: I think u understand my requiremnt if you know share code

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: I check it for wait sometime

Answer (score 0):

First Override this file in your custom module

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/ui-select.js

Modify the toggleOptionSelected function to select parent category.

```
   toggleOptionSelected: function (data) {

    var isSelected = this.isSelected(data.value);

    if (this.lastSelectable && data.hasOwnProperty(this.separator)) {
        return this;
    }

    if (!this.multiple) {
        if (!isSelected) {
            this.value(data.value);
        }
        this.listVisible(false);
    } else {
        if (!isSelected) { /*eslint no-lonely-if: 0*/
            this.value.push(data.value);

            /* to add current category and callled recursive function for selecting parent category*/
            $.each(data.optgroup, function( key, value ) {
                self.value.push(value.value);
                if (typeof value.optgroup !== 'undefined') {
                    self.childToParentIterate(value,'add');
                }
            });
            if (typeof data.optgroup === 'undefined') {
                self.childToParentIterate(data,'add');
            }

        } else {
            this.value(_.without(this.value(), data.value));
        }
    }

    return this;
}
```

Added new functions to check the parent category.

```
childToParentIterate: function(data, op){

    var self = this;

    var path = data.path;

    var level = data.level;

    $.each(this.cacheOptions.tree, function( key, value ) {
        var optgroup = value.optgroup;

        /*if you have your root level category with other label then change this label "Default Category" in below condition */
        if(value.label == "Default Category"){
            $.each(optgroup, function( optkey,optval ) {
                var label = optval.label;
                if(path.indexOf(label) != -1){
                    if(op == "add") self.value.push(optval.value);
                }  

                self.childIteration(optval,op,level,path);
            });
        }
    });
}

childIteration: function(data, op,level,path){

    var self = this;           
    if(data.level < level){
        var optgroup = data.optgroup;
        $.each(optgroup, function( optkey,optval ) {
            var label = optval.label;                   
            if(path.indexOf(label) != -1){
                if(op == "add") self.value.push(optval.value);
            }                    
            self.childIteration(optval,op,level,path);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to added in this code but in admin side edit product after i selected child cateogry after save than again check it same product not selected parent category automatically

Comment: I have to use it but getting this error after save it i select child product than automatically selected parent but other display i updated my question check it

Comment: Is c d b p s is your root level categories?

Comment: but this is not shown directly work it because not usable so how to remove it

Comment: please check in your code and reply me just work as default if i select child than parent selected only not showing root type  c d b p s

Comment: if you have time to tomorrow reply me i am waiting your answer its helpfull

Comment: hey i am try to remove in root category(c d b p s) because this is showing odd how to remove it please update code sent me

Comment: Kahn please look at my point

Comment: can you attach the image of your categories to your question.

Comment: I already attached it my question i apply code after display this like and in database some cateogry level issue facing not save proper and indexing time sql load

Comment: Khanplease help me regarding this and my category list all is anhor enable this code apply after in cateogry save issue and mention in my question image showing like this c d b h s like this is not shown in admin side beacuse its not good to ui

Comment: I am trying to figure out your problem. can you please go to Catalog->categories and attach categories SS

Comment: My issue is if i select one child cateogry randomly other child category selected and display above question image check it

Comment: Yes. I understand your issue.. I am asking for the screenshot of the your categories.. so I can feagure out...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94589/discussion-between-rizwan-khan-and-rv-singh).

Comment: please check my question added screenshots for category structure

Comment: i atached image u can understand properly

Comment: I can't see any c d b p s like categories..

Comment: please check it my updated question there describe it i am facing issue

Comment: not working it please help me

Comment: please look at my updated question

Comment: it is possibly because of  `if(path.indexOf(label) != -1){` in `childIteration` function. please can you check once.

Comment: okay let me check it again

Comment: In this function what is issue and what i change it if(path.indexOf(label) != -1){ in childIteration

Comment: In my fresh magento setup i use your code after child wise parent selected but in this label root "Default Category" not showing in admin side when i save the product. can u guide me how to fetch full recursive tree